# Jinja render text in HTML preserving line breaks

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a simple form like this:

```
class RecordForm(Form):    
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes')
```

I record the data in three paragraphs like this:

```
para1

para2

para3
```

In the template I would like to see the content of that record in read-only. (Not editable form)

record is this case the model containing the data:

```
<td>{{ record.notes }}</td>
```

-->

```
<td>para1 para2 para3</td>
```

What can I do to make it to show the multi-lines?

Comment: Also see http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/

Comment: Flask snippets are no longer provided. So I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572523/2648551) to this, hopefully adding some value in addition.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

All whitespace, including newlines, is turned into a single space in HTML.

Your options, from best to worst:

1. Put `white-space: pre-wrap;` on the containing element.  This tells HTML to show all whitespace exactly as it appears in the source, including newlines.  (You could also use a `<pre>` tag, but that will also disable word-wrapping, which you probably don't want.)
2. Treat the plain text as Markdown and throw a Markdown processor at it—one of the things Markdown does is wrap paragraphs in `<p>`.
3. In Python-land, do `.replace('\n', '<br>')`.  But this leaves you vulnerable to XSS because there might be other HTML-like junk in the string, and fixing that is a bit of a pain.

Comment: See http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/ for a Flask / Jinja2 specific option to turn newlines into `<br>` tags *and* ensure that any HTML embedded is rendered safely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the link throws a 404 :(

Comment: @MurphyAdam: colidyre's answer on this page contains the web archive link for the snippet, based on my comment.

Answer (score 3):

As [suggested by Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662898/jinja-render-text-in-html-preserving-line-breaks#comment95574197_18664389) (by linking [Flask snippet 28](https://web.archive.org/web/20190128010139/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/)), there is also the possibility to **add a custom filter for that**. The link is outdated, because Flask Snippets are [no longer provided](https://github.com/pallets/website/issues/41).

So I will provide [the snippet from web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20190128010139/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/) here:

> **nl2br filter**
>
> Posted by Dan Jacob on 2010-06-17 @ 05:03 and filed in Template Tricks
>
> This is a nl2br (newline to <BR>) filter, adapted from the Jinja2 example here:
>
> http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/api#custom-filters

```
import re

from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

_paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace('\n', '<br>\n') \
        for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

The link above about custom-filters seems to be outdated, too. Here is a similar link from the current stable version 1.1: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#registering-filters

I'm not really sure why he uses such a complicated result computation. For me the following code worked and it's much simpler. *Maybe, the variant above is better if you don't use `autoescape` (which I do not want to disable)?!* Anyway, now both variants are available:

```py
# custom_template_filters.py

from flask import Blueprint
from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

blueprint = Blueprint('custom_template_filters', __name__)

@evalcontextfilter
@blueprint.app_template_filter()
def newline_to_br(context, value: str) -> str:
    result = "<br />".join(re.split(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}', escape(value)))

    if context.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)

    return result
```

It is worth mentioning that the code snippet from Dan Jacob uses Python2, and I get the template filters running via Blueprint. For the sake of completeness I also provide the *app.py* using a factory method:

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask

def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    register_template_filters(flask_app=app)
    return app

def register_template_filters(flask_app: Flask) -> None:
    from . import custom_template_filters
    flask_app.register_blueprint(custom_template_filters.blueprint)
    return None
```

It is more or less an implementation detail how you will get the context filter working. The main idea is inside the function `nlbr` or `newline_to_br` itself. If you get the custom filter working, it is available in all your Jinja templates and you can use it like this:

```
{{ anystring | newline_to_br }}
```

Comment: Flask 2.0.x link: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/#registering-filters

Answer (score 1):

I've modified **nl2br filter** from documentation according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60572523/12851576 answer:

```
import re
from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter
from markupsafe import Markup, escape


@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    """Converts newlines in text to HTML-tags"""
    result = "<br>".join(re.split(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n)', escape(value)))

    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

It works for me. 
Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try solution directly for jinja:

`{{ record.notes.replace('\n', '<br>')|safe }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
{% for line in text.splitlines() %}
{{ line }}
{% endfor %}
</pre>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines