# How to render content with jinja using flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I use Flask in an application that displays some data from sqlite database. My problem is that the application displays text without the delimiter '\ n'. For example, a database entry has the following text:

```
Best Chiropractor in Dothan, really helped me with my posture and mood.                

One of the nicest, most knowledgeable doctors that have ever treated me!  One treatment in particular during my first visit changed my life infinitely for the better (not exaggerating).  Thank you Dr.
```

On the site:

```
Best Chiropractor in Dothan, really helped me with my posture and mood. One of the nicest, most 
knowledgeable doctors that have ever treated me! One treatment in particular during my first visit 
changed my life infinitely for the better (not exaggerating). Thank you Dr.
```

jinja:

```
{% if card[11] %}
   <h5 class="font-weight-normal">Reviews</h5>
   <p>{{card[11]}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: By default, HTML ignores whitespace, consider using CSS `white-space: pre-wrap;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jinja render text in HTML preserving line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662898/jinja-render-text-in-html-preserving-line-breaks)